# How to remove static variable but allow a variable to still be globally called?

Tags: java, static, libgdx, scene2d, tiled

I am using LibGDX with Scene2D and Tiled to create a 2d game. I have a class that reads the object layers and loads them into the game(which I am still deciding whether to make into a singleton). The problem is that in the class where everything gets updated, since I like to split my update and render into two classes, I have a `public static Stage stage` and I want to make it not static.

The problem with thaat is that I have a Mob class, which includes
   players and monsters, and I need the stage class in order to get all
   of the objects in the game and check for collisions.

In my Mob class I don't think/want to add Stage to the constructor as a parameter because it's an abstract class and I would have to put in a stage for the player class every time it is called.

If any additional information is needed, because I know you guys aren't wizards, I will put it up asap. I have three classes that I am working with here, the TiledMapHelper class, WorldController class, and Mob class.

Below is the class that converts my created level on Tiled into codeable objects for my game. The static ArrayLists will be changed to a Group class which is implemented into the stage class. The Stage Class holds all of the objects in my game.

```
public class TiledMapHelper {
    public static final int TILE_WIDTH = 512;
    public static final int MAP_WIDTH = 39 * TILE_WIDTH;
    public static final int MAP_HEIGHT = 45 * TILE_WIDTH;`

    public static ArrayList<Platform> platforms;
    public static ArrayList<Wall> walls;
    public static ArrayList<Door> doors;
    public static ArrayList<Stair> stairs;
    public static ArrayList<Ladder> ladders;

    private TiledMap tiledMap;

    public TiledMapHelper(TiledMap tiledMap) {
        this.tiledMap = tiledMap;

        initWalls();
        initGates();
        initPlatforms();
    }

    public void initWalls() {
        walls = new ArrayList<Wall>();
        MapObjects layerObjects = tiledMap.getLayers().get("walls").getObjects();
        for (MapObject mapObject : layerObjects) {
            if (mapObject instanceof RectangleMapObject) {
                Rectangle rect = ((RectangleMapObject) mapObject).getRectangle();
                Wall wall = new Wall(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
                walls.add(wall);
            }
        }
    }

    public void initGates() {
        doors = new ArrayList<Door>();
        stairs = new ArrayList<Stair>();
        ladders = new ArrayList<Ladder>();
        MapObjects layerObjects = tiledMap.getLayers().get("gates").getObjects();
        for (MapObject mapObject : layerObjects) {
            if (mapObject instanceof TiledMapTileMapObject) {
                if (mapObject.getName() == null)
                    continue;
                if (mapObject.getName().equals("Door")) {
                    int checkDoorType = Integer.parseInt((String) mapObject.getProperties().get("doorType"));
                    if (checkDoorType == 1) {
                        Door door = new Door(((TiledMapTileMapObject) mapObject).getX(),
                                ((TiledMapTileMapObject) mapObject).getY(), "door1C");
                        doors.add(door);
                    }
                    if (checkDoorType == 2) {
                        Door door = new Door(((TiledMapTileMapObject) mapObject).getX(),
                                ((TiledMapTileMapObject) mapObject).getY(), "door2C");
                        doors.add(door);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (mapObject instanceof RectangleMapObject) {
                Rectangle rect = ((RectangleMapObject) mapObject).getRectangle();
                if (mapObject.getName().equals("Stair")) {
                    String checkStairType = (String) mapObject.getProperties().get("isStair");
                    if (checkStairType.equals("upRight")) {
                        Stair stair = new Stair(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, "upRight");
                        stairs.add(stair);
                    }
                    if (checkStairType.equals("upLeft")) {
                        Stair stair = new Stair(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, "upLeft");
                        stairs.add(stair);
                    }
                    if (checkStairType.equals("downRight")) {
                        Stair stair = new Stair(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, "downRight");
                        stairs.add(stair);
                    }
                    if (checkStairType.equals("downLeft")) {
                        Stair stair = new Stair(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, "downLeft");
                        stairs.add(stair);
                    }
                }
                if (mapObject.getName().equals("Ladder")) {
                    String checkLadderType = (String) mapObject.getProperties().get("isLadder");
                    if (checkLadderType.equals("up")) {
                        Ladder ladder = new Ladder(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, "up");
                        ladders.add(ladder);
                    }
                    if (checkLadderType.equals("down")) {
                        Ladder ladder = new Ladder(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, "down");
                        ladders.add(ladder);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void initPlatforms() {
        platforms = new ArrayList<Platform>();
        MapObjects layerObjects = tiledMap.getLayers().get("platforms").getObjects();
        for (MapObject mapObject : layerObjects) {
            if (mapObject instanceof TiledMapTileMapObject) {
                if (mapObject != null) {
                    String checkPlatformType = (String) ((TiledMapTileMapObject) mapObject).getTile().getProperties().get("platformType");
                    if (checkPlatformType.equals("left")) {
                        Platform platform = new Platform(((TiledMapTileMapObject) mapObject).getX(),
                                ((TiledMapTileMapObject) mapObject).getY(), "left");
                        platforms.add(platform);
                    }
                    if (checkPlatformType.equals("middle")) {
                        Platform platform = new Platform(((TiledMapTileMapObject) mapObject).getX(),
                                ((TiledMapTileMapObject) mapObject).getY(), "middle");
                        platforms.add(platform);
                    }
                    if (checkPlatformType.equals("right")) {
                        Platform platform = new Platform(((TiledMapTileMapObject) mapObject).getX(),
                                ((TiledMapTileMapObject) mapObject).getY(), "right");
                        platforms.add(platform);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denfeet, I hope I'm not being presumptuous when I say that you already know a few ways to deal with the problem and you're asking for a recommendation as to the best one. If that's the case, this answer may be a bit more "general tips" than is usually helpful, but I can only wholeheartedly recommend a singleton **main game** class for your project. Yes, you could avoid it if you tried. The question is - is it worth your time (especially when you're trying to learn the library)? A static main game class will get you out a lot of the trouble you'll still fall into while creating your project and learning libgdx - and it won't take you ages to rewrite everything (I suppose I'm saying - learn from my mistakes and save the time I spent figuring this out the hard way :-)).
The only big trap for young players is the way Android handles static instances - recreate them all onResume to avoid it. Happy coding.

Comment: You're right, I do kind of give myself some solutions. I guess I'm just having trouble organizing my code. Everything was running smoothly, until I got to adding collision. It has taken me about two weeks to find the right way to add it in, and I'm tired of ripping my code down just to make a small change. This is what caused this problem, I have to change a whole bunch of code for this one little static variable. Thank you for your reply, I'll see if I can figure it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

A [Singleton](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton/java/1) object seems like it might solve your problem, since you can wrap an instance variable behind a static method call. I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve, though. Can you post your code?

EDIT:
The basic structure of a singleton Stage would look like this:

```
public class Stage{

    //Stage's fields

    //keep the constructor private
    private Stage(){

    }

    //Stage's methods

    private static class StageHolder { 
       //private field of the one Stage object
       private static final Stage INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }

    //public static message to access the one Stage
    public static Stage getInstance() {
       return StageHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

The idea is to hide the instance of the `Stage` as a private static field and use the `getInstance()` method whenever you need to access the `Stage`.

Comment: Sure, Ill post the class that converts the Tiled map level into coded objects.

Comment: I have posted the code, the static Stage variable is in my WorldController class. If you could help me change the code into a singleton that would be great.

Comment: Can you post the `Stage` class, too? @WonderfulWorld's idea of using a singleton main game class will work as long as you keep it on the smaller side as you develop.

Comment: If the `singleton` function is static, then the `SINGLETON` member it accesses should be static as well. One question I have is why did you deviate from the "Singleton in Java" page you linked to? The example on that site is no bigger and thread-safe.

Comment: Yep! I made a mistake trying to recreate it by hand without referencing the site I linked. Corrections have been made.

Answer (score 0):

Make a constructor of the class it is in, and use an accessor method to reference it

Comment: Yeah I just edited the question, I forgot to say that I didn't want to do that. Thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

Does every mob will have it's own specific stage?

I think it's ok for the stage to have a `createMob` method, which will take the configuration mob and create the mob. You can make the mob constructor have the stage parameter but without passing stage every time you wanted to create the class.

e.g:

```
abstract class Stage {
    public Mob createMob(MobConfiguration config) {
        ... // your mob creation method
        if (config.type == MobConfiguration.TYPE_PLAYER) {
            return new Player(this, config);
        }
    }
}
class Player extends Mob {
    public Player(Stage stage, MobConfiguration config) {
        // some initialization method
    }
}
```

Or you can put the `createMob` method to other class that own the Stage.